# Waiting for a chunk to load, before loading more

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm building an app, where I need to load data in chunks, I mean first load 5 items and then proceed with another 5, but I can't figure out how to do that. At the moment I chunk up my list of items, so I get a list of lists with 5 items in each. Right now the for-loop just fires away with requests, but I want to wait for the response and then proceed in the for loop.

I use alamofire, and my code looks like this.

```
private func requestItemsForField(items: [Item], completion: @escaping (_ measurements: Array<Measurement>?, _ success: Bool) -> ()) {
    let userPackageId = UserManager.instance.selectedUserPackage.id
    let params = ["userPackageId": userPackageId]

    for field in fields {
    let url = apiURL + "images/\(field.id)"

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.response-queue", qos: .utility, attributes: [.concurrent])
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, headers: headers()).responseArray(queue: queue, completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<[Item]>) in

        if let items = response.result.value as [Item]? {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "itemsLoadedNotification"), object: nil)
            completion(items, true)
        }
        else {
            print("Request failed with error: \(response.result.error)")
            completion(nil, false)
        }
    })
    }
}
```

This is where i chunk up my list, and pass it to the above.

```
 private func fetchAllMeasurements(completion: @escaping (_ measurements: [Item]?, _ done: Bool) -> ()) {
    let fieldSet = FieldStore.instance.data.keys
    var fieldKeys = [Item]()

    for field in fieldSet {
        fieldKeys.append(field)
    }

    // Create chunks of fields to load
    let fieldChunks = fieldKeys.chunkify(by: 5)

    var measurementsAll = [Measurement]()
    for fields in fieldChunks {
        requestItemsForField(fields: fields, completion: { (measurements, success) in
            if let currentMeasurement = measurements {
                measurementsAll.append(contentsOf: currentMeasurement)
            }
                completion(measurementsAll, true)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that you need to implement something like Pagination on the frontend. I suggest you to update backend for pagination however if you need to implement it on the frontend check this link -> [PagedArray](https://github.com/MrAlek/PagedArray)

Comment: You can try to use dispatch_group or dispatch_barrier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get number of measurements you will have (for example server has 34 measurements) with your request and then code something like

```
var serverMeasurementsCount = 1 //should be for first request

func requestData() {
    if self.measurements.count < self.serverMeasurementsCount {
        ...requestdata { data in
            self.serverMeasurementsCount = data["serverMeasurementsCount"]
            self.measurements.append(..yourData)
            self.requestData()
        }
    }
```

or call `requestData` not inside `completion handler` or somewhere else

edit: fixed code a bit (`serverMeasurementsCount = 1`)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for loop, it sounds like you need do something like `var index = 0` to start with, and call `requestItemsForField()` sending in `fieldChunks[index]` as the first parameter.  Then in the completion handler, check to see whether there's another array element, and if so, call `requestItemsForField()` again, this time sending in `fieldChunks[index+1]` as the first parameter.

Comment: But if I call requestItemsForField() again, we'll just have another completionhandler inside that?

Comment: If my idea works, you won't need to code another completion handler, because each completion handler will spawn another call to `requestItemsForField()`, and that call of course will also run its own completion handler when it finishes. etc. It will stop spawning calls when you've reached the end of the array, because the code in your completion handler will only spawn a new call if there's at least one more array element left.  The overall effect is that each new call to `requestItemsForField()` will not occur until the previous call has finished, which was your original goal.

Comment: To say it more plainly, each time `requestItemsForField()` reaches its completion handler, another call to `requestItemsForField()` will be made.  This is why only one completion handler needs to be coded.  And it won't go on forever because the code in the completion handler will only call the function if there's another array element left to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make a new recursive function to populate the items, add a new Bool parameter in closure as isComplete. then call the function on completion of isComplete boolean. to break the recursive function, add a global static variable of itemsCountMax, if itemCountMax == itemsCount break the recursive function.